# Plot a height v/s time graph in android for ball dropped from a height X

Tags: java, time, graph, height

**I am trying to build an application which shows the graph between all the heights and  time and displays total number of bounce, where height can be entered by the user and the coefficient can be altered too.**

**What I've done so far------->>>>>>**

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
double start_height = 20.0;
double x, y = 0.0;
double time = 0.0;
double velocity = 0.0;

double gravity = 10.0;
double step = 0.1;
//v=u+at
double h = 0.0;
double reachesGround = 0.0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GraphView graphView = findViewById(R.id.graphView);
    series = new LineGraphSeries<>();


    velocity = Math.sqrt(2*gravity*start_height);
    reachesGround = velocity/gravity;

    for (double i = start_height; i > 0.0; i--){
        //Time
        x += 0.1;
        //calculate next height to which the ball bounces
        y = i - ((10/100)*i);

        series.appendData(new DataPoint(x, y), true, (int) reachesGround);
    }

    graphView.addSeries(series);
    graphView.setTitle("Height v/s time graph");
}
```

**I wanna plot graph on the basis of below image**
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image: Ball dropped from a height (Graph plot)]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Krish15595/TaskBouncingBall

the formulae which you used is wrong and use the androidchart library for displayig of the linear chart